# Tkinter: Can you delete a tag permanently from Canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

I want to know if you can permanently delete a tag from a canvas. I know that when you draw something on a canvas, the canvas assigns a tag to the object. I also know that if you use `canvas.delete(tag)`, it still keeps the tag. I want to know how to delete the tag from the canvas.

```
>>> canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50)
1
>>> canvas.delete(1)
>>> canvas.create_rectangle(50, 50, 300, 300)
2
```

I don't the second rectangle to have a different tag/identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to aren't tags, they are object ids. They are not reusable.